# How to open downloaded documents file from blackberry access in windows explorer

Tags: blackberry

Im using outlook in blackberry access for security reason, but the attachment file that i downloaded from email can't be find or open in windows explorer, plz someone help me!,

Because in blackberry access,i can't edit or save edits in secure environment.

Any kind of idea really help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry Access for Windows includes an encrypted container for downloaded files. Access can be configured to restrict access to these files from the rest of the Windows System, which is why you don't see them in Windows Explorer.

A BlackBerry UEM admin can configure BlackBerry Access to allow the import and export of files from this secure container.  This is done in the BlackBerry Access app configuration.

This document explains how to change these settings: https://docs.blackberry.com/en/blackberry-dynamics-apps/blackberry-access/3_0/blackberry-access-administration-guide/lnb1484165962504/ndf1494880538789/aju1487865944450

The settings are explained in this document.  The two for this use case are "Enable export of downloaded files to OS file system (Windows and Mac)" and "Enable import of files from OS file system".
https://docs.blackberry.com/en/blackberry-dynamics-apps/blackberry-access/3_0/blackberry-access-administration-guide/lnb1484165962504/ndf1494880538789/bcp1488469362943

Alternatively, BlackBerry Access can be configured to allow the editing of documents from directly within its container. This configuration is explained here: https://docs.blackberry.com/en/blackberry-dynamics-apps/blackberry-access/3_0/blackberry-access-administration-guide/lnb1484165962504/Allow-users-to-securely-edit-files-within-an-app-in-BlackBerry-Access-on-Windows-or-macOS